# iOS Activity Indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, catransition

I trying to create activity indicator, currentView will be static and nextView will animate left to right, right to left, top to bottom and bottom to top.

I had written the code as below. The problem I am facing is, instead of all the four animations I am getting only one animation top to bottom animation. Can anyone help me how to run all the four animations one by one until a process is completed

```
statusImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
moveImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];

currentView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                            initWithImage:statusImage];


nextView = [[UIImageView alloc]
                         initWithImage:moveImage];

//Add your custom activity indicator to your current view
[self.view addSubview:currentView];
[self.view addSubview:nextView];

CATransition *transition1 = [CATransition animation];
[transition1 setType:kCATransitionPush];
[transition1 setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[transition1 setDuration:1];
[nextView.layer addAnimation:transition1 forKey:@"string1"];

CATransition *transition2 = [CATransition animation];
[transition2 setType:kCATransitionPush];
[transition2 setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight];
[transition2 setDuration:1];
[nextView.layer addAnimation:transition2 forKey:@"string2"];

CATransition *transition3 = [CATransition animation];
[transition3 setType:kCATransitionPush];
[transition3 setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
[transition3 setDuration:1];
[nextView.layer addAnimation:transition3 forKey:@"string3"];

CATransition *transition4 = [CATransition animation];
[transition4 setType:kCATransitionPush];
[transition4 setSubtype:kCATransitionFromBottom];
[transition4 setDuration:1];
[nextView.layer addAnimation:transition4 forKey:@"string4"];
```

Comment: You're really just repeating your earlier question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961016/ios-custom-activity-indicator. (And you didn't accept any answer there.) Also I notice that you are asking the wrong question; you keep making _assumptions_ about how to do this, rather than just describing the desired effect and asking _how_ to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone help me how to run all the four animations one by one until a process is completed

A layer can have only one transition animation at a time. There is no point supplying a key for a transition animation. The key will always really be `kCATransition`. Your `string1` etc. are pointless; just use `nil`. Moreover, your code makes no sense; multiple animations attached to a layer causes those animations to be performed *simultaneously* (if possible), not *successively*.

You need to *chain* the animations. Set up your code like this:

- Perform the first animation, giving it a completion handler. This completion handler is called when the first animation finishes.
- In the completion handler, do the second animation, giving it a completion handler. This completion handler is called when the second animation finishes.
- In the completion handler, do the third animation, giving it a completion handler. This completion handler is called when the third animation finishes.
- In the completion handler, do the fourth animation.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to use completion handler for CATransition can you give a sample code

Comment: You give the animation a delegate. CATransition is CAAnimation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/index.html Look at `delegate`.

Comment: Ok I will check that